# Using Kernow 7.1 to convert XML files and getting the following error

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

While using Kernow 7.1 to convert XML files, the following exception was thrown:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Error reported by XML parser
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you're giving it bad XML. If you can't see what's wrong with your XML, try loading it in an XML editor such as oXygen, which may have better diagnostics.